# What's the formula for the 'Adjusted p values reported -- single-step method' in glht function?

Tags: r, multiple-comparisons

For example, in the tutorial,

> data('recovery', package = 'multcomp')
>
> summary(recovery)

shows one control group b0 and three treatment groups b1~ b3. Then

> mod <- aov(minutes ~ blanket, data = recovery)
>
> library('multcomp')
>
> mc <- glht(mod, linfct = mcp(blanket = 'Dunnett'), alternative = 'less')
>
> summary(mc)

give

[image]

My question is, how the last column of Pr(< t)is calculated?

To be specific, the t value for b1-b0>=0 is -1.330, then why this Pr(< t) is 0.2411? What is the adjusted p value formula here?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you know what p-value adjustment is? It is done when doing multiple comparisons, as you are doing here. In your particular case, you are using Dunnett correction for p-values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the ANOVA statistical model
$$
y_{ij} = \gamma + \mu_i + \sigma\epsilon_{ij}, \quad 
i = 0, 1, \ldots, m, \quad j = 1, \ldots, n_i.
$$
where $\epsilon_{ij} \sim_{\textit{iid}} \mathcal{N}(0,1)$.

The number $\gamma$ is the overall mean and $\mu_i$ is the effect in group $i$. 
Group $0$ is considered to be a control group, and we are interested in 
the $m$ hypotheses 
$$
H_{0i} = \{\mu_0 = \mu_i\} \quad \textit{vs} \quad H_{1i} = \{\mu_0 > \mu_i\}.
$$
Let $H_0 = \bigcap_{i=1}^m H_{0i} = \{\mu_0=\mu_1=\cdots \mu_m\}$.

Consider the $m$ mean differences
$$
\bar{y_i} - \bar{y_0} = 
(\mu_i - \mu_0) + \sigma(\bar{\epsilon_i}-\bar{\epsilon_0})
$$
for $i = 1, \ldots, m$.

Hereafter we assume the null hypothesis $H_0$ is fulfilled, therefore 
$\bar{y_i} - \bar{y_0} = \sigma(\bar{\epsilon_i}-\bar{\epsilon_0})$.

We will derive the covariances between the standardized mean differences. 
Let's start by deriving the covariances between the $\bar{\epsilon_i}-\bar{\epsilon_0}$.

The $\bar{\epsilon_i}$ for $i = 0, 1, \ldots, m$ are independent and 
$\bar{\epsilon_i} \sim \mathcal{N}\left(0, \frac{1}{n_i}\right)$. 
Consequently, for $i = 1, \ldots, m$,
$$
\bar{\epsilon_i}-\bar{\epsilon_0} \sim 
\mathcal{N}\left(0, \frac{1}{n_i} + \frac{1}{n_0}\right)
$$
Now, let's derive the covariance between the $\bar{\epsilon_i}-\bar{\epsilon_0}$. 
One has
$$
\begin{align*}
\textrm{Cov}(\bar{\epsilon_i}-\bar{\epsilon_0}, \bar{\epsilon_j}-\bar{\epsilon_0}) 
& = 
E\bigl((\bar{\epsilon_i}-\bar{\epsilon_0})(\bar{\epsilon_j}-\bar{\epsilon_0})\bigr)
\\ & =
E(\bar{\epsilon_i}\bar{\epsilon_j}) + E(\bar{\epsilon_0}\bar{\epsilon_0}) 
- E(\bar{\epsilon_i}\bar{\epsilon_0}) - E(\bar{\epsilon_j}\bar{\epsilon_0}).
\end{align*}
$$
For $i\neq j$, each term is equal to $0$ except the second one:
$$
E(\bar{\epsilon_0}\bar{\epsilon_0}) = \frac{1}{n_0}
$$
Thus 
$$
\textrm{Cov}(\bar{\epsilon_i}-\bar{\epsilon_0}, \bar{\epsilon_j}-\bar{\epsilon_0}) 
= \frac{1}{n_0}
$$
for every $i,j \in \{1, \ldots, m\}$, when $i \neq j$.

Now, let's introduce the standardized mean differences
$$
\delta_i = 
\frac{\bar{y_i} - \bar{y_0}}{\sigma\sqrt{\frac{1}{n_i} + \frac{1}{n_0}}} 
\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1).
$$
for $i = 1, \ldots, m$. For $i \neq j$, the covariances are
$$
\begin{align*}
\textrm{Cov}(\delta_i, \delta_j) & = 
\frac{1}{n_0}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{n_i} + \frac{1}{n_0}}}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{n_j} + \frac{1}{n_0}}} \\
& = \frac{1}{n_0}\sqrt{\frac{n_0n_i}{n_i+n_0}}
\sqrt{\frac{n_0n_j}{n_j+n_0}} \\
& = \sqrt{\frac{n_i}{n_i+n_0}}\sqrt{\frac{n_j}{n_j+n_0}}.
\end{align*}
$$

Now let's introduce the statistics 
$$
t_i = \frac{\bar{y_i} - \bar{y_0}}{\hat\sigma\sqrt{\frac{1}{n_i} + \frac{1}{n_0}}} 
= \frac{1}{u}\frac{\bar{y_i} - \bar{y_0}}{\sigma\sqrt{\frac{1}{n_i} + \frac{1}{n_0}}}
$$
where 
$$
\hat\sigma^2 = \frac{\sum_{i=0}^m\sum_{j=1}^{n_i}{(y_{ij}-\bar{y}_i)^2}}{\nu}
$$ 
with $\nu = \sum_{i=0}^m n_i - (m+1)$, 
and where we have set $u = \frac{\hat\sigma}{\sigma}$.

It is known that 
$$
\nu u^2 = \nu\frac{{\hat{\sigma}}^2}{\sigma^2} \sim \chi^2_\nu
$$

Denote by $\mathbf{t}$ the vector ${(t_1, \ldots, t_m)}'$.
By the above, one has
$$
(\mathbf{t} \mid u) \sim 
\mathcal{M}\mathcal{N}(\mathbf{0}, \Sigma/u^2)
$$
where 
$$
\Sigma_{ij} = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{if } i = j \\
\sqrt{\frac{n_i}{n_i+n_0}}\sqrt{\frac{n_j}{n_j+n_0}} & \text{if } i \neq j
\end{cases}
$$

Therefore, $\mathbf{t}$ follows the multivariate Student distribution with 
$\nu$ degrees of freedom and scale matrix $\Sigma$ 
(see the paper *A short review of multivariate $t$-distribution* by 
Kibria & Joarder).

The *adjusted Dunnett $p$-value* for $H_{0i}$ vs the "less" alternative 
hypothesis $H_{1i}$ is 
$$
p_i = \Pr\left(\min_{i \in\{1, \ldots m\}}t_i < t_i^{\text{obs}}\right)
$$
where $\Pr$ is the probability under $H_0$.

One has 
$$
\begin{align*}
\Pr\left(\min_{i \in\{1, \ldots m\}}t_i < q\right) & = 
\Pr\left(-\min_{i \in\{1, \ldots m\}}t_i > -q\right) \\ 
& = \Pr\left(\max_{i \in\{1, \ldots m\}}-t_i > -q\right) \\
& = \Pr\left(\max_{i \in\{1, \ldots m\}}t_i > -q\right),
\end{align*}
$$
the last equality stemming from the symmetry of the (centered) multivariate 
Student distribution.

Let's write a R function computing 
$\Pr\left(\max_{i \in\{1, \ldots m\}}t_i \leq q \right)$.

```r
pDunnett <- function(q, n0, ni){
  if(q==Inf){
    return(1)
  }
  if(q==-Inf){
    return(0)
  }
  m <- length(ni) 
  Sigma <- matrix(NA_real_, nrow=m, ncol=m)
  for(i in 1:(m-1)){
    for(j in (i+1):m){
      Sigma[i,j] <- sqrt(ni[i]*ni[j]/(n0+ni[i])/(n0+ni[j]))
    }
  }
  Sigma[lower.tri(Sigma)] <- Sigma[upper.tri(Sigma)]
  diag(Sigma) <- 1
  nu <- n0 + sum(ni) - m - 1
  mnormt::pmt(rep(q,m), mean=rep(0,m), S=Sigma, df=nu, maxpts=2000*m)
}
```

Now let's try an example.

```r
data("recovery", package = "multcomp")
recovery
##    blanket minutes
## 1       b0      15
## 2       b0      13
## 3       b0      12
## 4       b0      16
## 5       b0      16
## 6       b0      17
## 7       b0      13
## 8       b0      13
## 9       b0      16
## 10      b0      17
## 11      b0      17
## 12      b0      19
## 13      b0      17
## 14      b0      15
## 15      b0      13
## 16      b0      12
## 17      b0      16
## 18      b0      10
## 19      b0      17
## 20      b0      12
## 21      b1      13
## 22      b1      16
## 23      b1       9
## 24      b2       5
## 25      b2       8
## 26      b2       9
## 27      b3      14
## 28      b3      16
## 29      b3      16
## 30      b3      12
## 31      b3       7
## 32      b3      12
## 33      b3      13
## 34      b3      13
## 35      b3       9
## 36      b3      16
## 37      b3      13
## 38      b3      18
## 39      b3      13
## 40      b3      12
## 41      b3      13
# samples
ys <- lapply(split(recovery, recovery$blanket), function(df){
  df$minutes
})
# sample sizes
sizes <- lengths(ys)
ni <- sizes[-1]
# degrees of freedom
nu <- sum(sizes) - length(ni) - 1
# pooled variance estimate
s2 <- sum(sapply(ys, function(y){
  sum((y - mean(y))^2)
})) / nu
# Student statistics
n0 <- sizes[1]
y0bar <- mean(ys[[1]])
yi <- ys[-1]
ti <- sapply(yi, function(y){
  (mean(y) - y0bar) / sqrt(1/length(y)+1/n0) / sqrt(s2)
})
# adjusted p-values
sapply(ti, function(t) 1 - pDunnett(q = -t, n0, ni))
##        b1.b0        b2.b0        b3.b0 
## 0.2411790515 0.0000585819 0.0924376838
```

Let's compare with the `multcomp` package:

```r
fit <- lm(minutes ~ blanket, data = recovery)
library(multcomp)
multcomps <- glht(fit, linfct = mcp(blanket = "Dunnett"), 
                  alternative = "less")
summary(multcomps)
## 
##   Simultaneous Tests for General Linear Hypotheses
## 
## Multiple Comparisons of Means: Dunnett Contrasts
## 
## 
## Fit: lm(formula = minutes ~ blanket, data = recovery)
## 
## Linear Hypotheses:
##              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(<t)    
## b1 - b0 >= 0  -2.1333     1.6038  -1.330 0.2412    
## b2 - b0 >= 0  -7.4667     1.6038  -4.656 <0.001 ***
## b3 - b0 >= 0  -1.6667     0.8848  -1.884 0.0925 .  
## ---
## Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
## (Adjusted p values reported -- single-step method)
```

The *adjusted Dunnett $p$-value* for $H_{0i}$ vs the "greater" alternative 
hypothesis $\{\mu_0 < \mu_i\}$ is 
$$
p_i = \Pr\left(\max_{i \in\{1, \ldots m\}}t_i > t_i^{\text{obs}}\right)
$$

```r
sapply(ti, function(t) 1 - pDunnett(q = t, n0, ni))
##     b1.b0     b2.b0     b3.b0 
## 0.9958029 1.0000000 0.9995174
multcomps <- glht(fit, linfct = mcp(blanket = "Dunnett"), 
                  alternative = "greater")
summary(multcomps)
## 
##   Simultaneous Tests for General Linear Hypotheses
## 
## Multiple Comparisons of Means: Dunnett Contrasts
## 
## 
## Fit: lm(formula = minutes ~ blanket, data = recovery)
## 
## Linear Hypotheses:
##              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>t)
## b1 - b0 <= 0  -2.1333     1.6038  -1.330  0.996
## b2 - b0 <= 0  -7.4667     1.6038  -4.656  1.000
## b3 - b0 <= 0  -1.6667     0.8848  -1.884  1.000
## (Adjusted p values reported -- single-step method)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Stéphane! @Stéphane Laurent

Answer (score 2):

As explained in the foundation for the `multcomp` package, ["Simultaneous Inference
in General Parametric Models" (Hothorn et. al, 2008)](https://scholar.google.dk/scholar?q=Simultaneous+Inference+in+General+Parametric+Models&hl=da&as_sdt=0&as_vis=1&oi=scholart), the single step method works when the model provides a asymptotically, normally distributed estimate vector

$$
\hat\theta \sim \approx N(\theta, \Sigma),
$$

and a consistent estimator of $\Sigma$, $\hat\Sigma$. Assume that one wants to test $k$ hypotheses that can all be written in form $H_0^j: K_j\theta=m_j$, where $K_j$ is a matrix with one row. Define then $K$ as the stacked $K_j$'s (think `rbind` function of R), the hypothesis $H_0$ as the hypothesis that all $H_0^j$ are true, $m=(m_1, \dots, m_k)$, and define then the test statistic vector

$$
T = \text{diag}(K\hat\Sigma K^*)^{-1/2}(K\hat\theta-m)  \stackrel{\text{Under }H_0}{\sim\approx} N(0,R).
$$

The single-step adjusted p-value, which controls the probability of false-positive conclusion among the $k$ hypotheses, is

$$
1-P(\max(|T|)\leq t)=1-\int_{-t}^t\cdots\int_{-t}^{t} f_{N(0,\hat R)}(t_1, \dots,t_k) \text{ d}t_1\dots\text{d}t_k.
$$

where $t$ is an absolute test statistic value (representing a realized value of an entry of $T$) and $f_{N(0,R)}$ is the density function of a multivariate normal distribution. For many models, the asymptotic normal distribution can be replaced by an exact $t$-distribution, which the `glht` function will do.